# Field converted to phone number link on iPad and iPhone

Tags: android, html, ios, ipad

I work on a software generating some HTML to make an UI for our client. As we are making a tablet version of our software, I am in charge of resolving some bugs appearing only on the tablets. 
That's why I have to prevent some number fields to be considered as phone numbers and therefore to have a link to make a phone call on them. 
My problem is that I can't use the meta `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` because of some old legacy code preventing the use of meta (we have to be in quirks mode on IE). 
Do somebody has an other solution to prevent the tablet to recognise my numbers as phone numbers?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you *need* to be in Quirks mode? This mode represents a severely outdated version of Internet Explorer. This question aside, your issue is with iOS, so the [internet-explorer] tag isn't needed.

Comment: I don't exactly know. I'm new on the project and my coworkers told me that it was needed for some legacy code so I believed them. It seems that we should rewrite a lot of code to stop the behaving and we are understaffed right now so ... I believe it will stay that way for a long time ^^ And thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could accomplish this. One way is to use CSS to enforce a "normal" appearance for the text (wrap it in a div/span, if need be), and use `pointer-events:none` to prevent tapping it from having any effect in iOS.

Comment: I tried your solution and the `pointer-events:none` successfully prevented anyone from tapping the field. However, I can't change the color which stay blue. I tried to change it in red to be sure it change: `a.TextFieldSpan:link {color:red};
a.TextFieldSpan:hover {color:red};
a.TextFieldSpan:visited {color:red};
a.TextFieldSpan:active {color:red};` but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?